# How to connect sqlite3 with Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

HI. I am new to android application development and I am trying to create an app with sqlite3. For that I created DB through the command prompt. Program runs successfully but did'nt make changes in my DB.
I need code snippeet for that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try Notepad Tutorial for primers on DB connection

Link
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Here is another link if you want to port the sqldb you created outside android environment to the device. 
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/